# Suggested Users or Users you may know or Similar Users in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Guys I want to craete a list of users called Suggested users or users you may know for a particular user,i have a field called Area of interest in user account,so i wuld like to list users who have same value for Area of interest field with current users, I am not very good at relationship and contextual filters

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you, you should have a look at the 
http://drupal.org/project/views
module.

This module provides a list of users, nodes, +++
Filters can easylie clicked.

[druapl views module: how to create a list of users](http://mostrey.be/creating-user-list)

[youttube video: basic druapl views module instructions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eV__oOckAPM)